# How to make TEXT RENDER stand facing the camera of my character and also for the camera of simulation?

Tags: camera, rotation, unreal-4, text, blueprints

**I have an actor (Minion) with a Text Render just above it mesh:**

[image]

As you have seen, I defined your rotation as absolute, so the text does not rotate along with the actor.

**In the game the rotation setting is good and acceptable at various times:**

[image]

**At other times it is very bad:**

[image]

**An example of what I want is something like the life of the champions in the League of Legends:**

[image]

**I would also like to know how to do this when I am simulating:**

[image]

I've made some attempts at the camera of my main character. And I got some of what I tried.

**Character Blueprint:**

[image]

I know I could put on the Event Begin Play because the camera does not rotate.

**Minion Blueprint:**

[image]

**I did (partially):**

[image]

Ignoring the fact that the text is inverted. I tried **Split Struct** and added 180 to each of the 3 axes (ROLL, PITCH, YAW) and I could not solve it anyway.

**Simulating nothing works:**

[image]

---

**EDIT 1 (Attempt made based on a_rrat's answer)**

**Blueprint:**

[image]

I think I tried all the combinations and none worked the way I would. The combination defined in the image made the Text Render spin.

---

**EDIT 2 (Correction of the attempt I made wrongly)**

**Correction that I did:**

[image]

With the answer I was given I noticed a marked improvement.

**Result 1:**

[image]

Besides the value is no longer inverted.

**Result 2:**

[image]

But I still have not got what I like.

**Result I am looking for:**

[image]

I wish life would be displayed the same way anywhere on the map the character is on.

---

**EDIT 3 (Removing roll)**

**Blueprint:**

[image]

In game there was no difference.

---

**EDIT 4 (Trying to explain what I want to happen)**

I think that because I can not speak English and have to use programs to translate things for myself, I do not know the best way to explain my doubts, the best words, among other things.

I think the best way then to try to explain what I want is with images.

I want regardless of the location or angle life is seen in the same way.

**Image:**

[image]

**Image:**

[image]

**Image:**

[image]

In the LEAGUE OF LEGENDS anywhere on the screen that the champion is, the life bar appears the same way. I would like to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly create a Widget Blueprint with custom size.

[image]

- Remember the size you set.
- Preferably place the text size equal to that of the widget.
- Add the widget component to your actor.
- In the Space option, select screen.
- In the Widget Class option, select the widget that you created
- In the Size option, place the same one you placed in the widget.

[image]

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is two things :

1. You are just applying the camera rotation to the text instead of billboarding the text
2. You are rotating all the axes of your text, when you need to rotate it on one axis only

   What you can do instead :

   - Use `Find Look At Rotation`, with your billboard and camera position as inputs
     http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/BlueprintAPI/Math/Rotator/FindLookatRotation/
   - Break the result, and use only the value you need. In this case, you need only Yaw, and you can use then `Break Rot` and `Make Rot` to set Pitch and Roll to 0, and keep the right Yaw value

Comment: I clarified in the issue I made. I did not modify the 3 axes at one time, but one at a time. After 2 in 2 and also the 3 at once. No combination worked.

Comment: Have you tried using the technique suggested instad of applying the camera rotation directly to your text?

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested, but I think I may have been wrong about something.

Comment: You have a BP node specifically for that FindLookAtRotation, where you pass the text WorldLocation and CameraLocation (as goal) this node returns you a rotator which you should apply to the TextMesh.

Comment: @ColdSteel Did I do what's different?

Comment: In your question - what did you plug in to FindLookAtRotation target node ? It doesnt look like a camera’s world location.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso what you did so far is getting the rotation of the camera and applying it to the text - what you should do is to get a direction (vector) from the text to the camera, and use this to determine the text rotation

Comment: I've corrected my mistake. I'm getting close to what I like.

Comment: Break the rotator result and remove the Roll from there

Comment: @ColdSteel I did what you said, nothing has changed.

Comment: @Boneco Sinforoso, try to remove the pitch as well then

Comment: @ColdSteel Nothing has changed, either.

Comment: @Boneco Sinforoso, why are you setting relative rotation ? You should set a world rotation.

Answer (score 2):

To make this work in the same way as your League of Legends example, you need to put a Text inside a Widget component which is attached to your character, not TextRender.

The reason for this is that you can set the Widget to display at the same location in world or screen space so it moves with the character and does so automatically with rotation.

Create a Widget as you normally would by going to Add New -> User Interface -> Widget Blueprint

[image: Create Widget Blueprint UE4 image]

Drag a Text component onto the canvas, use the font options on the right hand side to get it the size you want, set the Anchor in the middle then shrink the canvas size to match the text.

IMPORTANT!  Make a note of the size X and size Y of your Text component.

[image: Set Text Component to Size on Widget UE4]

Now go into your character and add a Widget component to it.

[image: Add Widget to Player Character UE4]

In the details tab, under User Interface, change the Draw Size to that of your text component and make the WidgetClass the name of your created Widget.

[image: Amend Widget Class Details Player Character UE4]

Move the widget around as necessary to get it above the character as you wish.  If it's a third person character, you may also need to set the rotation to 180°.

Finally, under User Interface, change the Space setting from World to Screen.  This will make the widget disappear from the blueprint (though you can always change it back if you need to make adjustments) but when you play, it will be with the character in the same location at all times.

[image: Final Result of Widget to Character UE4]

Using this method will make the widget appear exactly behind the character.  If you want to have it rotate with the character, you need to get the default Z rotation of the character (270° in the Third Person character) and the default of your widget (180° in my example) and calculate the difference per tick.

[image: Widget With Rotation on Character UE4]

This will now always display with the front of the text, no matter the rotation of the character on screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In edit 4 of the question I think I can explain exactly my desire.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso See my last paragraph about using tick to rotate the widget component.

Comment: Yes, I managed to make it static, but the 2 other axes are not the way I would like it.

Answer (score 2):

This was years ago but I wanted to add in, for anyone curious and struggling like me, how I did this.

You set the world rotation of the component in question to the value of your camera's rotations as follows. Get the PlayerCameraManager, get Camera Rotation, and break out the rotator. You're going to make a rotator for your SetWorldRotation pin and input

X, Y * -1.0, Z + 180

From camera rotation.

This image shows what I mean. The blue line is mean turning this into a Quat and back to a rotator, just incase gimbal lock messes with this at all. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Most simple algorithm for understanding is just get ForwardVector, then multiply it my -1.0f and convert to Rotator.
In C++ it's like
`FRotator NeedRotator = (Camera->GetActorForwardVector() * -1.0f).Rotation();`

Comment: How would that be with blueprints?